# ops-agent-fluent-bit throws [storage] format check failed for server hosting Odoo

Tags: google-compute-engine

We have a compute engine instance hosted by Google that will lock up seemingly at random. SSH will not connect and the only way to recover appears be forcing a restart of the machine.

When I checked the logs in the monitor I can see that right at 2AM when my application monitoring tool says things went down the CPU spiked then dropped, the disk IO had a spike and memory and disk space utilization appears to stopped monitoring.

[image: monitor logs 1]

[image: monitor logs 2]

Also there are a few logs with a high severity that appeared.

[image: error logs]

Looking them up I see a connection with [fluent-bit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ops-agent/issues/463). That issue was fixed in 2.15.0 of the google-cloud-ops-agent, but my version is 2.27.0 so that should be good.

```bash
dpkg -l | grep google-cloud-ops-agent
ii  google-cloud-ops-agent                2.27.0~debian11                amd64        Google Cloud Ops Agent
```

What would the right next step be to investigate the root cause of these lockups?